# Expectation and variance of Uniform Distribution

Tags: self-study, uniform-distribution, moment-generating-function

If X is uniformly distributed over (0,1),I want to calculate $E[X^2],E[X^n]$ and $Var[X^n]$

**Answer**:I tried to get 2nd derivative of mgf  $\frac{e^{tb}-e^{ta}}{t(b-a)}$ to compute $E[X^2]$.

I tried to get nth derivative of the mgf of uniform distribution to calculate $E[X^n]$, but I didn't get the correct answer.

Answers provided to me are $E[X^2]=\frac13,E[X^n]=\frac{1}{n+1},Var[X^n]=\frac{1}{2n+1}-(\frac{1}{n+1})^2$

So I need some help from any member to arrive at the correct answers.

Comment: Why would you differentiate the mgf n times? Does the quesion specifically point to that direction? I'd rather integrate...

Comment: Because $\phi^n(t)=E[X^n]$ at t=0

Comment: For uniform(0,1), the mgf is simpler than the one you stated in your question: $(e^{t}-1)/t$. if you want to obtain some sort of generalized n-th derivative, it should have a recurrence relation between subsequent derivatives but it doesn't seem to be the case. Could you define what $\phi$ is?

Comment: Do you have to specifically use the mgf in this exercise?

Comment: Is there  any other method to compute $E[X^2],E[X^n],Var[X^n]?$

Comment: Certainly there is, via the integral referred to in the first comment under your question.

Comment: @Glen_b Do you want to use L'hopital's  rule here?

Comment: No. Why would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

$$E(X^k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^k f(x) dx$$

and the fact that $f(x)$ is $1$ between $0$ and $1$ and zero elsewhere, you can write

$$E(X^k) = \int_{0}^1 x^k dx$$

This integral is very easy to evaluate, indeed it's a standard elementary integration problem. With a tiny bit of additional effort you can also compute the variance.

Comment: Answer provided by the author is $\frac13$ to $E[X^2]$

Comment: @Dhamnekar I'm not sure why you're telling me that, but that's correct. You should be able to show it using the above suggestion. Do you know the antiderivative of $x^k$, or failing that, can you work it out? It's quite basic.  Did you read the `self-study` [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) in relation to hints and guidance? You should show a proper attempt at applying the above hint.

Comment: I have got the answers to $E[X^2],E[X^n],Var[X^n]$.I found your answer very useful to arrive at correct answers.